# How to pass email body to an application

Tags: batch-file, outlook

I have recently discovered that you can make rules in Outlook.  These can be triggered by a number of events and do a number of things.  One such thing is [launching an application](http://tech2.in.com/how-to/software/how-to-trigger-an-application-via-email-in-outlook/593772).

[image: Outlook Rules Wizard]

Seeing this, I thought I might be able to automate a few emails.  However, some of these processes will likely require information in the body of the email, which I have no idea how to pass into the application.

Is there a way I can pass the email body of the message that triggered the event into the application being launched?

**Note:** *I'm using Outlook 2003 on XP*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible to pass information as parameters to your script. But that would mean lots of rules with static information being passed based on the email subjects. Without using anything besides outlook itself and an external batch script, it does not seem possible to pass elements of the email to the script. But I hate to say 'impossible'.

There are some [really cool things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156795/microsoft-outlook-create-rule-run-application-script-python) that can be done with outlook and more advanced languages though :-).

Edit: [Live and learn](https://superuser.com/questions/464000/how-to-replace-text-in-the-body-of-an-incoming-message-with-a-hyperlink-in-outlo). It is possible with vb.

Comment: Great piece of info and it answers this question.  However, using `Item.Body` in VB seems to cause a [pop-up with Outlook](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18156470/1618257)