# Turn off Outlook warning or extend timer

Tags: outlook-2003

I've made a rule in Outlook VB

```
Sub Test(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim message
  message = Split(Item.Body, vbCrLf)
  ...
End Sub
```

However, anytime it runs I get this message:

[image: Warning message]

I'm fairly certain this is coming from `Item.Body`, and I can silence this alert for up to 10 minutes, but I would rather just turn it off entirely.

Is this possible?  If not is there a way I can extend the timer past 10 minutes?

*This is relating to Outlook 2003 on Windows XP.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn this off by creating\setting the value of CheckAdminSettingsto 1 in the Registry Key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Security

see [MS Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885682) and [MS Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329765/en-us)