# Automating a process in windows

Tags: python, shell, powershell, vbscript

We have a web application which alerts when a server refresh is needed. When the alert comes we have to open a windows application,give the server name & refresh the server. Can this process be automated by using any scripting languages?

Comment: How does the web application alert that a server needs refreshing?

Answer (score 3):

You alert system could launch a python script. For example take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156795/microsoft-outlook-create-rule-run-application-script-python) for a simple way to launch a python script when outlook gets an email.

Then you can use  [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/), it has a very simple API:

```
from pywinauto import application

app = application.Application.start("notepad.exe")
app.Notepad.MenuSelect("Help->About Notepad")
app.AboutNotepad.OK.Click()
app.Notepad.Edit.TypeKeys ("pywinauto Works!", with_spaces = True)
```

Also see: [Why write yet another automation tool if there are so many out there?](http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/index.html#why-write-yet-another-automation-tool-if-there-are-so-many-out-there) for a comparison with other existing tools.

Comment: that is exactly what pywinauto does.